# HPE ProLiant ML110 Gen9 Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, hp-proliant, ubuntu-14.04

I want to buy a HPE ProLiant ML110 Gen9 Server and install Ubuntu Server 14.04TLS on it.
My question is, does Ubuntu Server 14.04 TLS support HPE ProLiant ML110 Gen9?
Here are the specifications [server specifications](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/hpe-proliant-ml110-gen9-n2g73a-intel-xeon-e5-2603-v3-8gb-35-server-4684847?tagIds=615)

Thanks for recommendations.

Comment: HP typically lists (lor inks to) supported operating systems in the *"standard features"* section of the [products quickspecs](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/gethtml.aspx?docname=c04545452) pages.   

There is also a listing on which HP systems Ubuntu is a [supported OS](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/ubuntu.aspx). The ML110 isn't listed as supported on Ubuntu by HP there.

Comment: I don't recommend using Ubuntu on any HP servers as bare metal. the hardware support is very poor with Ubuntu and you'll miss out on the value-add features of the system. I would provide more information, but this question was closed to answers.

Comment: Which server are you recommended to buy dell? It should be for small business.

Comment: I don't recommend using Ubuntu on bare metal hardware. Virtualized, it's fine, but you'll feel pain if you run it on enterprise server equipment.

Comment: Which linux do you recommended to install bare metall, Suse Linux?

Comment: Redhat, CentOS or suse.

Comment: @ewwhite  This question seems to have been reopened again, maybe you could elaborate on your answer? I am myself curious to understand the specific differences of the OSes you mentioned vs Ubuntu or other Linuxes on pro server hardware as I was not aware there are any.

Comment: Which server are you recommended to buy for small business. HP or DELL?